# Why was my comments removed from related answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, comments

I recently did a code review on [Tic Tac T-OO: Design and Implementation](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/101595/78136), and as such took a little interest in the other answers related to this question. Currently there are only two, and I got into a little discussion regarding the use of one or two dimensional arrays to represent the tic-tac-toe game board.

I was clearly not able to get my meaning across, so after a few comments the other answerer asked to move it into a char. I went into the [chat room](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27284/discussion-between-legato-and-holroy), asked a few questions and the other user did not respond, and has now left the room. In addition the original comments on [the answer](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101652/78136) has now been removed. The last comment before going into chat room was the "I appreciate your input, ...".

My questions are as follows:

- Is it normal to remove the comments from the original answer?
- Has I behaved inappropriately when commenting since the comments has been removed?

Just to be clear: I don't have any issue with choosing different designs or solution, I was merely trying to understand why he wanted to push a one dimensional array, and considered that a better option. And I do *not* want to discuss that here. Here I want to get an understandig if this is normal behaviour, and how to handle such a situation.

I also see that the comments could be considered ´chatty´, but shouldn't one or two be left standing so as to indicate that there is a question regarding the use of one or two dimensional arrays?

Comment: We'll really have to wait for the moderator that actually removed the comments, but generally speaking, comments are second class citizens that aren't really meant to be permanent. If they're too chatty, or obsolete for some reason, they're likely to be removed.

Comment: *Especially* if you take it to chat as per [Legato](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101595/tic-tac-t-oo-design-and-implementation#comment185999_101652)'s comment. The comments are automatically moved to the chat room at that point. The chat room then serves as the 'public record' per sé. If comment chains start getting too long, a message will appear prompting you to take the discussion for chat. As it says before you make a comment: Comments are not the place for extended discussion.

Comment: I've seen the 'chat invitation' before, but I've not experience the removal of the comments leading up to it before. And I do agree (and understand) that comments are not a place for extended discussion. But in some of the cases I've seen there has been better references to indicate what the chat is about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly answering your two questions:

> - Is it normal to remove the comments from the original answer?

Yes it is perfectly normal to remove comments from answers. Especially comments that resulted in a change of the answer are removed. There is an extra comment flag reason for that ("obsolete").

Also long-winded comment threads are generally removed, since they clutter up the Q&A and often are better off in chat. Additionally old (and resolved) comment threads often drown out newer "signal". (Think "show 24 more comments")

> - Has I behaved inappropriately when commenting since the comments has been removed?

No. Inappropriate behaviour is only present, when comments are removed because they are offensive, overly rude or too chatty. In this case you raised a point about the answer, there has been discussion, which you moved to chat. At this point the comments *are already* obsolete.

As such they can be removed. And rightfully were.

Checking the Answer, there still is the comment by Legato, asking to move the comments to chat. As such there's still an indicator of a conversation about the answer, even more permanently preserved than comments :)

Comment: But what about the comments now not reflecting anything regarding the one/two dimensional issue, besides the indirect reference that something might be commented in a chat? And is it normal to abstain from participating in the chat when you initiate it?

Comment: @holroy the chatroom is currently in use, and the user you were talking to is there. Some people need their sleep :) The one vs. two-dimensional issue seems to be one of preference to me (didn't research deep into this, though) as such the comments aren't of viable importance, IMO.